# Is there a way to make labels from list numbers?

Tags: python-3.x, list, tkinter

i'm still learning python so please be patient.

i'm trying to create a program to help myself at work. this is my second day of working with python, and I've come to an impasse. working with Tkinter, i have an Entry box that i put in names that i have compiled to a list.
My question is: how to i get the names to individually display onto a Label? Ideally i want the program to sort the list alphabetically, then assign each name a number in accordance to their position on the list, then to create a label to display "1: PersonName" then for the second spot create another label under it that reads "2. PersonName" and so on.

i'm not fully aware of all the python capabilities so i'm unsure if this is even possible, so if someone would have an idea or place to start, please help me out.

I dont really know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, `names` is your list of names, `master` is the Frame to put the names in:

```py
names.sort()
for i in range(len(names)):
    Label(master, text=str(i+1) + ': '+ names[i]).pack()
```